# How can I validate that text input does NOT match between 2 fields in Shopify's "Create Account" form?

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid

I am trying to combat the spam bot(s) that are flooding my Shopify "Create Account" form.

The fake user accounts always use the same identically spelled random "First Name" and "Last Name", so if I could make the submission not execute with the condition that the "First Name" and "Last Name" can not match, I think this might solve my problem.

What is easiest way to implement this? Any advice would be appreciated.

I have working knowledge for altering code in Shopify, but I am no professional.

I've already tried Geo-IP blocking, but it appears the bot is gaining access through my own (US), so that did not work. I also tried adding a required check box to verify the reading of our terms before submission, to no avail, the bot ticks the box it and they come through.

I've included our customers/register.liquid page below.

```
{% layout settings.customer_layout %}
<div class="bump">
<section id="blacktop">
<div id="template">
  <div id="customer">

      <!-- Create Customer -->
      <div id="create-customer" data-aos="flip-right">
           <h1>Create an Account</h1>
        <div class="template_header">
        </div>

        {% form 'create_customer' %}
          {{ form.errors | default_errors }}


        <input id="fname" type="text" name="confirm" value="" />


          <div class="clearfix large_form">
            <label for="first_name" class="login">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="customer[first_name]" id="first_name" class="large fnamer" size="30" />
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix large_form">
            <label for="last_name" id="lname-reg" class="login">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="customer[last_name]" id="last_name" class="large" size="30" />
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix large_form">
            <label for="email" class="login">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30" />
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix large_form">
            <label for="password" class="login">Password</label>
            <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
          </div>



<input type="hidden" id="customer_tags" name="customer[tags]" value="Illuminati"/>

          <div class="action_bottom">

            <input id="create-btn" data-callback="onSubmit" class="btn" type="submit"  value="Create">

            <span class="note"><a href="/account/login">or Login</a></span>
          </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/pages/products/#welcome"/>

        {% endform %}
      </div><!-- /#create-customer -->
  </div>
  </div>




</section>


  <script>

  var checker = document.getElementById('fname');
  var sendbtn = document.getElementById('create-btn');
  checker.onchange = function() {

    sendbtn.disabled = !this.checked;
  };

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
input[name="confirm"]{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</div>
```

Hopefully this could work. I've seen many posts of people experiencing the same bot submissions with identical names. The new "customers" never do anything else to our shop like try to purchase, but it is a problem mainly because of the amount of fake accounts, plus they get automatically imported to HubSpot through integration as "sales leads".

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack the submit on the form with Javascript. So if the user clicks submit or the bot clicks submit it is going to trigger an idiot check. You can check the name fields and decide if they are legit or not. If not, do nothing. If they seem legit, let the submit happen and carry on.